# Cannot get 2nd viewlist to take list as argument

Tags: java, javafx

can not get the second created view list to take in the "cartItems" value items added as argument no matter how I worded or what I place into the listview. Tried to .getitems(cartItems) but it would not take. 
Is their any other statements or way i can word this so that idems added with the add button move to the second list for checkout

[image: Output]

Full Code

```
package shoppingcart1;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ShoppingCart1 extends Application
{
    private Label answer;
    private Label price;
    ListView <String> listView;
    ListView <String> listView2;
    private String[] listArray = new String[7];
    private String[] listArray2 = new String[7];
    private List cartItems = new List();

    private final double salesTax = 0.07;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        answer = new Label("Price: ");
        price = new Label("");
        String line;
        int index = 0;
        File file = new File("BookPrices.txt");
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file);

        while (fileReader.hasNext())
        {
            line = fileReader.nextLine();
            String[] titles = line.split(",");
            listArray[index] = titles[0];
            index++;
        }
        //list view items book
        listView = new ListView < > ();
        listView.setPrefSize(200, 170);
        listView.getItems().addAll(listArray);

        //list view items book
        listView2 = new ListView < > ();
        listView2.setPrefSize(200, 170);
        listView2.getItems();


        // create label to display the selection
        Label selectedNameLabel = new Label("Select a Book");
        Label price = answer;

        //Button for selection
        Button addButton = new Button("Add to Cart");
        addButton.setOnAction(new AddButtonListener());

        //Delete button
        Button removeButton = new Button("Remove Item");
        removeButton.setOnAction(new RemoveButtonListener());

        //Delete button
        Button clearButton = new Button("Clear All");
        clearButton.setOnAction(new ClearButtonListener());

        //Checkout
        Button checkoutButton = new Button("Check Out");
        checkoutButton.setOnAction(new CheckoutButtonListener());

        //Controls to HBox
        HBox hbox = new HBox(listView, listView2);

        //Controls to HBox2
        HBox hbox2 = new HBox(10, addButton, removeButton, clearButton, checkoutButton);
        hbox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        //Controls to VBox
        VBox vbox = new VBox(10, hbox, selectedNameLabel,
                price, hbox2);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        //Show
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    // Add button
    public class AddButtonListener implements EventHandler < ActionEvent >
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String value = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            cartItems.add(value);
           // answer.setText("Price: " + Calc());
        }

    }
    // Subtract Button
    public class RemoveButtonListener implements EventHandler < ActionEvent >
    {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String value = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            try {
                cartItems.remove(value);
                //answer.setText("Price: " + Calc());
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
    }
        //Clearbutton
        public class ClearButtonListener implements EventHandler < ActionEvent > 
    {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) 
        {
                    cartItems.removeAll();
                    answer.setText("Price: " + Calc());
        }
    }

        //Checkout
        public class CheckoutButtonListener implements EventHandler < ActionEvent > 
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) 
        {
                    answer.setText("Price: " + Calc());
        }
    }

    // Button Calculations
    private String Calc() {
        String line;
        double totalCost = 0.0, costOfItem = 0.0;
        File file = new File("BookPrices.txt");
        Scanner fileReader = null;
        try
        {
            fileReader = new Scanner(file);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException el)
        {
            el.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (fileReader.hasNextLine())
        {
            line = fileReader.nextLine();
            String[] cost = line.split(",");

            String title = cost[0];
            costOfItem = Double.parseDouble(cost[1]);

            for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.getItemCount(); i++)
            {
                if (title.equals(cartItems.getItem(i)))
                    totalCost += costOfItem;
            }
        }

        DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###.##");

        return myFormatter.format((salesTax * totalCost) + totalCost).toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong `Event` import, and `ListView` simply doesn't have a `getValue()` method. What are you trying to do?

Comment: make a checkout cart that adds or deletes selected values from the listview

Comment: I meant "What are you trying to do" specifically in the sense of the code `booklistView.getValue()` (not in the sense of your entire project). But what's wrong with the code you commented out, instead of the call to the non-existent method?

Comment: idk how to really explain it other then pick the selected name, give it a value and have it add and subtract. the commented out code was test code that wasent working. still working with possibly rewritting it but cant figure out a method to get it to work

Comment: "pick the selected name". Ok, if you are trying to get the selected value, you already have the code to do that, but you commented it out: `//String selected = booklistView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();`

Comment: i tried
```
String book = boollistView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (boollistView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null)
        {
            if (book.equals("I Did It Your Way"))
                cart += 11.95;
        }
```
But it didnt work

Comment: No one can help you if all you say is “it didn’t work”.

Comment: trying to figure out how else to word it, their are no erros printed to screen, build says successful. but not working as intended as the cart value does not increment or decrement

Comment: So show the new version (in your question, not in comments), including the code where you update the text of the label.

Comment: Your action event handler should work. But: you never update the `price` label, so it will never show the updated price. Somewhere in your action event handler you have to update the `price` label, for example by adding `price.setText("Price "+cart);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem with your code is that member `cartItems` of class `ShoppingCart1` is a `java.awt.List`. You can't mix AWT and JavaFX components. In the code below, I changed that to be `java.util.List`.

In the below code, I made the minimum amount of changes in order to make the buttons do what I think you want them to. I wouldn't say the below code constitutes a completed JavaFX application. My intention (and hope) is that it allows you to overcome the barrier you are currently stuck at.

```java
public class ShoppingCart1 extends Application
{
    private Label answer;
    private Label price;
    ListView <String> listView;
    ListView <String> listView2;
    private String[] listArray = new String[7];
    private String[] listArray2 = new String[7];
    private List<String> cartItems = new ArrayList<>();

    private final double salesTax = 0.07;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        answer = new Label("Price: ");
        price = new Label("");
        String line;
        int index = 0;
        File file = new File("BookPrices.txt");
        try (Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file))
        {
            while (fileReader.hasNext())
            {
                line = fileReader.nextLine();
                String[] titles = line.split(",");
                listArray[index] = titles[0];
                index++;
            }
        }
        //list view items book
        listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.setPrefSize(200, 170);
        listView.getItems().addAll(listArray);

        //list view items book
        listView2 = new ListView<>();
        listView2.setPrefSize(200, 170);
        listView2.getItems();

        // create label to display the selection
        Label selectedNameLabel = new Label("Select a Book");
        Label price = answer;

        //Button for selection
        Button addButton = new Button("Add to Cart");
        addButton.setOnAction(new AddButtonListener());

        //Delete button
        Button removeButton = new Button("Remove Item");
        removeButton.setOnAction(new RemoveButtonListener());

        //Delete button
        Button clearButton = new Button("Clear All");
        clearButton.setOnAction(new ClearButtonListener());

        //Checkout
        Button checkoutButton = new Button("Check Out");
        checkoutButton.setOnAction(new CheckoutButtonListener());

        //Controls to HBox
        HBox hbox = new HBox(listView, listView2);

        //Controls to HBox2
        HBox hbox2 = new HBox(10, addButton, removeButton, clearButton, checkoutButton);
        hbox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        //Controls to VBox
        VBox vbox = new VBox(10, hbox, selectedNameLabel, price, hbox2);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        //Show
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // Add button
    public class AddButtonListener implements EventHandler < ActionEvent >
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String value = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            listView2.getItems().add(value);
            cartItems.add(value);
            answer.setText("Price: " + Calc());
        }
    }
    // Subtract Button
    public class RemoveButtonListener implements EventHandler < ActionEvent >
    {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String value = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            try {
                cartItems.remove(value);
                listView2.getItems().remove(value);
                answer.setText("Price: " + Calc());
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
    }
    //Clearbutton
    public class ClearButtonListener implements EventHandler < ActionEvent > 
    {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            cartItems.clear(); //removeAll();
            listView2.getItems().clear();
            answer.setText("Price: " + Calc());
        }
    }

    //Checkout
    public class CheckoutButtonListener implements EventHandler < ActionEvent >
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            answer.setText("Price: " + Calc());
        }
    }

    // Button Calculations
    private String Calc() {
        String line;
        double totalCost = 0.0, costOfItem = 0.0;
        File file = new File("BookPrices.txt");
        Scanner fileReader = null;
        try
        {
            fileReader = new Scanner(file);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException el)
        {
            el.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (fileReader.hasNextLine())
        {
            line = fileReader.nextLine();
            String[] cost = line.split(",");

            String title = cost[0];
            costOfItem = Double.parseDouble(cost[1]);

            for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.size() /*getItemCount()*/; i++)
            {
                if (title.equals(cartItems.get/*Item*/(i)))
                    totalCost += costOfItem;
            }
        }
        DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
        return myFormatter.format((salesTax * totalCost) + totalCost).toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! I did the get item before and couldent get it to work, but seems when i add it to the add, delete and clear it works perfectly. and i didnt actually have to make the bottom edit, left the bottom as the original and it works flawlessly. Thank you so much abra, you have been the most helpful.

Comment: well spotted major error :) But ... do not replicate error in the question, they tend to stick and proliferate! f.i., in no particular order: a) do not swallow errors in catch blocks b) do not catch errors that can't be thrown (see the doc which can be expected `list.remove(Object)`) c) stick to java naming conventions d) do not instantiate a DecimalFormat by its constructor e) do not use full-fledged classes for eventHandlers, except they are doing something useful. IMO, a to d are mandatory - only e can be left as-is for "closeness" to original code (OP insists on doing it wrong ;)

Comment: just checked bullet d: the formatter uses the default locale (as does String.format), doc might be a bit over-cautious. ignore that part of the comment :)

Comment: @kleopatra I feel very honored to have received praise from you. I did write in my answer that the code is not a complete solution which was intended to be a hint to the OP that [s]he has other issues with the code. Was that too subtle? I didn't want to make too many changes so as not to overwhelm the OP. Nonetheless I did sneak in a `try-with-resources`.

Comment: I did read it :) Nevertheless, answers should be as correct (otherwise the OP and others simply assume it's okay and we'll see the same errors in her next n questions) .. in b) I  didn't mean the file reading, but the removeButton handler